# WebSocket request-response subprotocol

Tags: websocket

WebSocket provides a bi-directional communication like a human being talks.
The client can send data to the server and the server can send data to the client anytime.
But what about the request-response behavior?
The client could ask something to the server and wait for a response.
It seems that Websocket doesn't provide anything to link client data (request) to server data (response).

It's probably the work of the subprotocol and I have some ideas on how to do it (send an ID with the request and wait for a reponse with the same ID within a timeout period).

In order to not reinvent the wheel and to save some time, I looked over the internet for an existing solution but I haven't found anything related (maybe bad keywords).

So, is there anyone aware about this kind of work or am I missing something?

Comment: WebSockets aren't really meant for that classic HTTP request-response behavior. They're *event-based*, like JavaScript events: they sort of come unsolicited.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The WebSocket Application Messaging Protocol (WAMP) https://wamp-proto.org/ provides RPC (Remote Procedure Call) and PubSub (Publish & Subscribe) messaging patterns on top of raw WebSocket for that purpose.

WAMP is a proper WebSocket subprotocol, uses WebSocket as transport and JSON as a payload format. RPC is implemented using 3 messages, and those messages contain a "Call ID" to correlate asynchronous RPC server responses to client initiated procedure calls.

Disclaimer: I am author of WAMP and some (open-source) WAMP implementations. Its an open initiative, with others already started to get on the boat. Ultimately, there should be a WAMP RFC properly defining the protocol .. but its still in the early stages.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I'm working on Java both side and you don't seem to have Java Implementations so I'll be happy to join :)

Comment: Great! Join us! Btw: we have an Android specific Java client-only implementation: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid

Couple of WAMP resources: http://wamp.ws/spec, https://github.com/tavendo/wamp, the mailing list mentioned in the latter, and (mostly for historical reasons), the mailing list for Autobahn: http://groups.google.com/group/autobahnws.

Comment: @oberstet I have a related and similar question in terms of the websocket and Apache server continually sending repeated information to the client instead of just once. Located at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071639/configure-apache-server-and-websockets-to-prevent-repeated-pulling-of-same-data any suggestions?

Answer (score 15):

I would use JSON-RPC 2.0.

http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification

Each message would be a JSON object.  The protocol states if it is a call that wants a response (coupling with id), or a notification.

A JSON-RPC aware application could easily check if the message object contains a method, signifying a call, or not, signifying a response.

I'm about to build a javascript lib to handle json rpc over websocket, with ajax as fallback…

Comment: My plan is to add a JSON-RPC server in js as well, so the backend can send requests to the browser in the same way.

Comment: +1 JSON-RPC is actually very suiting for WebSocket, and specifically PubSub (despite the statements to contrary on WAMP's site). The biggest pretend issue with WebSocket vs JSON-RPC is lack of response, hence, supposedly ruling out use of JSON-RPC and requiring use of "notification" mode in JSON-RPC over WebSocket. However, sticking with JSON-RPC calls that contain `id` (flagging non-notification mode) element actually allows bi-directional async responses to come under that ID (just need to pass ID to callback on b/e) and you can continue using notification mode for response-less requests.

Answer (score 5):

> (send a id with the request and wait for a reponse with the same id until a timeout period)

I created a lib that does exactly that, called WebSocketR2 (where R2 means Request Response): https://github.com/ModernEdgeSoftware/WebSocketR2

It also handles reconnecting to the server if a connection is lost, which could be helpful if you are doing web sockets through a load balancer.

The final result is you can implement callbacks on the web socket send function like this:

```
var request = {
    action: "login",
    params: {
        username: "test",
        password: "password"
    }
};

ws.send(request, function(response){
    console.log(response)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the [SwaggerSocket](https://github.com/wordnik/swaggersocket), which is a REST over WebSockets protocol supported with all major Java WebServer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [msg-rpc](https://github.com/rooseve/msg-rpc), it provides **bidirectional** rpc support over simple message interface, include WebSocket.

Not only the simple rpc, which could cover "client request / server response" behavior, it also supports "server request / client response" behavior, which is via the Rpc Service.

To get start with, there're sockjs and socket.io examples .

Answer (score 1):

I'm running a simple request-response program using websockets. See "[Websocket Server Demonstration](http://highlevellogic.blogspot.se/2011/09/websocket-server-demonstration_26.html)". You can download the webpage source code.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: After almost 11 years, there's still a clear answer. The question was about request-response using WebSockts. WebSockets can handle request-response as is clear from the demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on this discussion but, [BrokerJS](https://github.com/mind-matrix/brokerjs) is a reactive alternative you can try in NodeJS. Define a data model and subscribe websocket connections to specific keys of the model. Any changes to server side variable are automatically reflected on the client side. I think this will save you a lot of boilerplate code. Even better, you can still use the old-fashioned websocket messaging parallel to the new reactive way of doing things. It is far from a polished product and arrays are a headache. But in conjunction with something like VueJS, React or Svelte, I think it will save you a lot of trouble.

Disclaimer: I am the the author of BrokerJS.