# Implement request-response exchange between node processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, process, ipc

Let's say I have a parent node process that forks a child process. I want to create a request-response mechanism between them, so that the child can send a message (JSON) to the parent and wait for a response and the other way as well.

I don't want to use HTTP because I want the mechanism to be as tight and low-latency as possible, and HTTP usually has some overhead. Also, HTTP is a client-server protocol and I want something bi-directional. (I'd be happy to know if the overhead is negliglbe or as bad as using pipes, TCP sockets directly, or WebSockets in this situation; it'd make my job easier).

The end-result I want is something like this. Note that this code is in TypeScript for clarity, not because the answer has to be in TypeScript too.

```
class Communicator {
    // Callback for when a message is received by the Communicator
    // Resolve returns a response to the sender, reject returns an error
    onMessage : (data : any) => Promise<any>;

    // Sends an object to the other process, and returns a promise
    // that resolves with the response or rejects with the error reason
    send(data : any) : Promise<any>;
}
```

In these case, I'm going to assume we use the native `process.send` mechanism, but if another system like WebSockets are better, it'd be a bit different:

```
// PARENT

let cp = require("child_process").fork("./child.js");

let comm = new Communicator(cp);

await comm.send({property : 1});
```

.

```
// CHILD

let comm = new Communicator(process);

await comm.send({property : 1});
```

The request/response system should support both Success-type and Error-type responses, as well as Error non-responses that indicate the underlying protocol failed.

How should I implement this in Node? There are lots of issues I can think of if I tried to do this naively, since multiple requests and responses can be running in parallel. Is there a library that already does this? Should I just use HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to the problem appears to be to use WAMP over WebSockets:

[WebSocket request-response subprotocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882370/websocket-request-response-subprotocol)

However, since in this case we're talking about IPC and processes running inside a single machine, we're not really constrained with regard to the transfer protocol (we could even use raw sockets if we really wanted). There is also a built-in messaging system between parent and child processes.

So maybe it's possible to use WAMP over something else, or come up with another solution.

With regard to WAMP, one package we can use is [autobahn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobahn).